# Total Variation Distance Triangle Inequality

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

I have the following definition for the total variation distance between two probability measures on a metric space $X$.  $d(\mu,\nu) = \inf\{\mathbb{P}(V\neq W) : \text{$V:\Omega\rightarrow X$ has distribution $\mu$, $W:\Omega\rightarrow X$ has distribution $\nu$}\}.$  How do I check that the triangle inequality holds for this function?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \text{If } U\ne W \text{ then } \big( \text{not }U=V=W\big). \\[8pt]
\text{So } & \Pr(U\ne W) \\[8pt]
\le {} & \Pr(\text{not } U=V=W) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(U\ne V \text{ or } V\ne W) \\[8pt]
\le {} & \Pr(U\ne V) + \Pr(V\ne W)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Recall that TV between two functions (density function) is $L_1$ norm with a scale $1/2$. So all the properties of $L_1$ follow.

Answer (score 0):

The total variation distance is a special case of minimal metric. So, triangle inequality follows from this fact.

For example, in the paper "Metric distances in spaces of random variables and their distributions", V. M. Zolotarev, section 1.4, there is a proof.